# Questions on arrays in solidity

Tags: arrays, solidity

1. In the first image I'm receiving an error when I add the `[]` before `dnaDigits`. It doesn't seem to like that I have a value assigned to it (16 in this case). Why is this? Shouldn't I be able to assign multiple values due to the [] being added next to uint? The error message is in the second image if needed. Also how would I go about adding more than one element to this variable? The only programming language I know is R. In that I would write `c(16, 25, 28)` to add 3 elements to a variable.

   [image: image 1]

   [image: image 3]
2. The way arrays are created for a struct seems confusing to me and I'm wondering if that's because I'm not fully understanding it. In the third image I've coded how I would have thought a struct array should be coded. What is the purpose of having the code in row 15 of the first image? Having to refer to zombies then Zombie in the function seems messy when referring to just zombies (like in the second image) would be simpler to read/understand.

   I assume there's a reason for the coding being set up in this way but I don't get it.

   [image: image 2]

Comment: Post code as text, not images of text please.

Answer (score 0):

1. `uint[] dnaDigits` is declaring an array of undefined size, therefore you can not initialize it in bulk since is an empty array of size 0.
2. There are 2 mistakes in the second:

a) First, you need to define the struct, and then, create an array of its type:

```
Struct Zombie{
string name
uint dna
}
Zombie[] zombies;
```

b) then you need to create a struct in memory and then add it to the array

```
Zombie memory z;
z.name=_name;
z.dna=_dna;
zombies.push(z);
```